# What does "malloc" do in C/MPI?

Tags: c, mpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is malloc doing in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213403/what-is-malloc-doing-in-this-code)

Can aynone explain what this code do, especially "malloc"? I use this in C with MPI...

```
vector = ( double * ) malloc ( size_of_vector * sizeof ( double ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < size_of_vector; i++ ) {
        vector[i] = (double) ( i + 0.211 );
    }
```

I know this for malloc:

> The function malloc() returns a pointer to a chunk of memory of size
>   size, or NULL if there is an error. The memory pointed to will be on
>   the heap, not the stack, so make sure to free it when you are done
>   with it.

Comment: wellcome to stackoverflow. I think you misunderstand the purpose of this site. this does not replace your favorite search engine. Please show some effort before you ask questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allocates enough memory to store `size_of_vector` doubles and then initializes that memory to hold `size_of_vector` doubles each with a value calculated based on its position in the vector.

The `malloc` call allocates the memory.

Answer (score 0):

malloc - allocates memory.  The parameter passed in is the number of bytes to return.

The above code is allocating enough memory for an array of doubles (with a length equal to size_of_vector).

The for loop just initializes the array, which that each slot in the array is .211 higher than the one before it.

Answer (score 0):

malloc is used to allocate memory in C.

Each data type, for instance, a double might be 8 bytes.
`sizeof ( double )` gets this size and 
`size_of_vector * sizeof ( double )` is the actual size of the vector.

So what you are essentially doing is passing in the actual size of the vector into malloc and you would expect malloc to reserve that amount of memory for you to use.